# Microsoft research on fact extraction from the web?

Tags: extract, fact

Some time ago I had accidentally found website which was apparently product of Microsoft research on fact extraction from the web, more specifically from the Wikipedia. Right now I would like to have better look into how it works, but the problem is i can't find it, maybe somebody knows what I am talking about and could give me directions or link to it?

Thank you!

Comment: No not that one, that was already working prototype

Answer (score 1):

There is a hint of it here:

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/collaboration/global/scholar2005.aspx#Kaisser

Looks like MSR where sponsoring a Phd student who was working on it a few years ago. There is a link to his website, might be worth giving him a shout.